# Wordpress form posting

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I am facing a problem while self posting form data, when I hit submit button the page should display the data inserted in the input box,
but it does not show the data....

Here is my example form

```
<?php 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
    {
        $mail = $_POST['mail'];
        echo $mail;
    }
?>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="myForm">
    Mail : <input id="mail" name="mail" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

This should obviously display the mail value from the input box. But it does not work. Then I tried to change the action attribute value to "mywordpress/index.php/customer-details-2/"

Since I am new with Wordpress, any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add the posted value in your input text box as :

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"    name="myForm">
Mail : <input id="mail" name="mail" type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['mail'])) ? $_POST['mail'] : '' ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I am assuming that you want to show data inside input text box.
Hope it helps you.

Comment: hello Jenis Patel....I tried your given solution, but the PHP codes inside the value attribute is automatically placed inside the input box when the page is loaded...not working